# Boolean Diference not working

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to create a wheel on blender, so I can create an URDF. I use this meshes lick rollers, but when I try to use the boolean diference it does not affect the 3d. It look likes the same model. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Did you hide the cutting geometry? If it stays in place you cannot see the newly created shape.

Answer (score 1):

Some people will tell you to stay away from booleans because they can be a hassle and seemingly randomly not work, but if you get used to them you'll find out the exact cases where it won't work and can learn to avoid them.

That being said, here's my checklist:

1. Manifold geometry (in some, very very speciffic cases (maybe for logos or something) you will use booleans on non-manifold geometry), but it is generally considered to be a very bad idea, unless you know exacty what you are doing.
2. Normals : press the *Overlays Options* button on the top right and toggle *Face Normals* if you see any red, go fix it immediately: <kbd>Tab</kbd>  into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> , then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
3. Line-vertex / vertex-vertex intersections: if all else fails, it means you have a vertex exactly on an edge or on top of a vertex, and Blender can't tell what's supposed to be inside or outside. if you are using a literal mesh you should try to move the objects around just *slightly*, if you are using non-destructive modifier operations, it's always clever to use a prime number of faces on your bevels and screws, this will greatly decrease the chance of such intersections